# Why sub string selection fails silently when we try to fetch invalid range?

Tags: python

In a single character string when I try to fetch second character python fails quite verbosely which is correct and expected behavior.

```
print 'a'[1]
```

However when I try to fetch an invalid sub sequence range, it fails silently.

```
print 'a'[1:]
```

What is the reason for the difference in behavior?

Comment: There's little difference between "fails silently" and "succeeds with an empty return value".

Comment: @GregHewgill, if you refuse to fail then you must return *something*. Your choices are an empty list, or `None`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Of course, by "empty" I meant "empty list" (or "empty string" in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually `slicing` never generates any `error` in case of `strings` and `lists`:

**for eg.**

```
>>> s='abc'
>>> s[-1000:1000]
'abc'
```

works fine.

On the other hand, while accesing `Indexes` that are not defined will always raise an `IndexError` in both `strings` and `lists`:

```
>>> s[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    s[4]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Hence, slicing != indexing. Interesting!

Comment: Slicing and indexing are similar in both concept and syntax, so just saying "they're different" is somehow unsatisfying.

Comment: @MarkRansom even dictionaries use the same `[]` syntax, and in their context `[]` is  different from `indexing` and `slicing`,so guess it's just the overloading feature of python. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This makes more sense when you look at how mutable slicing on a list behaves:

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[10] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    a[10] = 2
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> a[10:] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
```

Modifying a slice past the end tacks the new values onto the end, equivalent to doing `a.extend([1, 2, 3])` (although slightly different if your start point exists). This isn't surprising once you get your head around:

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> a[2:4] = range(10)
>>> a
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But since you can modify this slice, it would be slightly surprising for trying to access it to be an `IndexError` - nowhere else in the language does getting something you can set fail with anything other than a `NameError`. But, `NameError` wouldn't make sense here - Python *has* found the an object with the right name, and has called a method on it.

Therefore, Python doesn't consider past-the-end slicing as an error with lists. With that in mind, why should accessing a slice behave differently between the builtin sequences? Strings (and tuples) are immutable, so slice assignment will always fail - but seeing what value is there isn't a mutation.

So, really, the ultimate reason is - it is because the devs felt this behaviour is less surprising than the other possible behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics differ:

```
 print 'a'[1]
```

tries to index into a non-existent (ie invalid) index/location, which *is* an error.

```
 print 'a'[1:]
```

simply returns, based on the specified range, an empty string (`''`), which is *not* an error.

I.e.,

```
In [175]: 'a'[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 1 'a'[1]
IndexError: string index out of range


In [176]: 'a'[1:]
Out[176]: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

A slicing operation is different from an index operation. An index returns an element, and a slice returns a range, even an empty range or an empty string.

An array with a single element has two "boundaries" where indexing pointers can be: 0 and 1. You can slice like `'a'[0:1]` and you`ll get the string (or range in a list or array) that lies between these positions.

If you slice from the leftmost border to the end, the reading goes to the end, where it already is, and you get the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It can be thought of this way:

When you use `a[1]`, it is assumed that you exactly know what you want to access (in this case - second element in a string). Since `a[1]` does not exist python raises an exception.

However, range operator `a[1:]` is implemented with the semantics that one may not know the exact range of data so even if you specify indices that are very large (random guess) you will still get the valid portion of the string (or sequence). The reason you get an empty string in this case is that there are no elements in the string in this range `a[1:]`.

Hope this helps.